# Cannot start Repl

Tags: dart, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to install a repl for Dart according to the page https://pub.dev/packages/repl

After `dart pub global activate repl` I got the following error message:

```
$ drepl
The Dart VM service is listening on http://127.0.0.1:8181/V3ekGjDx3nQ=/
The Dart DevTools debugger and profiler is available at: http://127.0.0.1:8181/V3ekGjDx3nQ=/devtools/#/?uri=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8181%2FV3ekGjDx3nQ%3D%2Fws
2.18.7 (stable) (Thu Jan 12 10:44:08 2023 +0000) on "macos_x64"
Type `exit()` or Ctrl-d to quit.
Unhandled exception:
Instance of 'InvalidPathResult'
#0      repl (package:repl/repl.dart:36:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      wrappedMain (file:///Users/gefei/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/repl-0.1.0+2/bin/main.dart:18:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no obvious fix for this exception. Also,
[`package:repl`](https://pub.dev/packages/repl) is no longer maintained and the author is recommending users take a look at [`package:interactive`](https://pub.dev/packages/interactive) instead, so you might have more luck trying that package instead.